# java server client share main

Tags: java, multithreading, tcp

Is it possible for one java program operate as both the client and server? I have tried implementing threads but I have problems with race conditions. Should I persist or is there a simpler solution?

The program is for demonstration purposes so the user input to the client and server will be the same string every time the program is run. i.e. client: "hello server" server: "hello client" client "good bye server" server: "good bye client."

Comment: Usually you want to have things separated because of the nature of the architecture, however in some games that allows LAN interaction one of the players is the host, therefore he is the server and also a client. Usually multi threading there is to allow multiple clients to the same server. It depends on what you are trying to implement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Start the program two times: once as a client, once as a server. The distinction can be made using a command line switch. That way, client and server run in different processes and thus race conditions due to concurrent memory access are prevented.

Answer (score 0):

> Is it possible for one java program operate as both the client and
>   server?

Answer is yes, you can have a single program with two threads acting as client and server. There are real world implementations doing the same. For point to point communication similar approach is used for example SIP end points written in java.